React Context API preventing App from Loading
I am trying to use React Context API in my project. I have made the StateProvider and reducer files and even wrapped the whole App in the StateProvider while also passing the initial state and the action and states (in reducer). However, my react app is just showing a plain white screen when I load on the browser.
This is my index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { StateProvider } from './StateProvider';
import reducer, { initialState } from './reducer';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <StateProvider initialState={initialState} reducer={reducer}>
      <App />
    </StateProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();


Below is my StateProvider.js
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

//BUILD A LAYER
export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) => {
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
}

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext)

Below is my reducer.js
export const initialState = {
  basket: [],
};

function reducer(state, action) {

  switch(action.type) {

    case 'ADD_TO_BASKET':
      //Logic for adding code to basket
      break;

    case 'REMOVE_FROM_BASKET':
      //Logic for removing from basket
      break;

    default:
      return state;

  }
}

export default reducer;

When I remove the StateProvider from the index.js, as shown below in the snippet of code, the react app loads perfectly on the browser.
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

Please provide a solution as this is my capstone project for a course.


StateProvider has no return statement, so it puts nothing on the page

export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children}) => {
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
}

Your component does not have a return statement, so it is telling react to put nothing on the page. The fix is as follows:
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => {
  return (
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
      {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
  );
};


